# iPython can't find package

Tags: python, windows, conda

First of all, I´m on windows, with conda installed. The steps I followed:

```
conda create -n snowflakes python
pip install pykml
```

After I do this, I can access pykml if I type
    py
(Enters python command line with >>>)
but I can't if I type ipython
(opens python cmdline with [1]).

Is it possible to access it via ipython?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have created a new conda environment named `snowflakes` but that you installed pykml in your root environment.  Probably your ipython and your python are in different environments -- what does `where ipython` and `where python` return?

Try the following:

```
conda create -n snowflakes python
activate snowflakes
pip install pykml
conda install ipython
```

Now you should be able to do `import pykml` in both `ipython` and `python`.  I would also consider using conda, instead of `pip`, to install `pykml`. In other words, you can do `conda install -c ioos pykml`.